# dynamically classify categories

Tags: algorithm

I am new at the idea of programming algorithms.  I can work with simplistic ideas, but my current project requires that I create something a bit more complicated.

I'm trying to create a categorization system based on keywords and subsets of 'general' categories that filter down into more detailed categories that requires as little work as possible from the user.

I.E.

Sports >> Baseball >> Pitching >> Nolan Ryan

So, if a user decides they want to talk about "Baseball" and they filter the search, I would like to also include 'Sports"

User enters: "baseball"

User is then taken to Sports >> Baseball

Now I understand that this would be impossible without a living - breathing dynamic program that connects those two categories in some way.  It would also require 'some' user input initially, and many more inputs throughout the lifetime of the software in order to maintain it and keep it up to date.

But Alas, asking for such an algorithm would be frivolous without detailing very concrete specifics about what I'm trying to do.  And i'm not trying to ask for a hand out.

Instead, **I am curious if people are aware of similar systems that have already been implemented and if there is documentation out there describing how it has been done.  Or even some real life examples of your own projects.**

In short, I have a 'plan' but it requires more user input than I really want.  I feel getting more info on the subject would be the best course of action before jumping head first into developing this program.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for *related concepts* or the *generelizing concept*? For example, if Baseball will return MLB, or basketball return NBA rather then sprts - will it be fine?

Comment: @amit The latter would be more preferable.  Sports >> NBA >> basketball.  I think it would be best to have a wiki of sorts. Users being allowed to enter categories, but not required.  This would feed the base amount of the info into the system.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO It isn't as hard as you think. What you want is called `Tagging` and you can do it Automatically just by setting the correlation between tags (i.e. a `Tag` can have its meaningful information plus its reation with other ones. Then, if user select a Tag well, you related that with others via looking your ADT collection (can be as simple as an array).

```
Tag: 
    Sport
Related Tags
    Football
    Soccer
```

...

I'm hoping this helps!

Comment: i see the complexity coming from the dynamic nature of the idea. I don't want to manually enter categories. To make things more clear, look at this in terms of a message board.  Topics go from general to detailed (folder by folder). So, lets say someone wants to talk about hockey based on your example...the sub category would need to be created under "sport."  But what if the user is lazy and doesn't want to seek out "Sport" as the general category, or if they simply don't know what should go above it.

Comment: Either you invert the tag relation (Football to know it's under Sport) and you create a base tagging system or you create a knowledge model and train it to seek for those relationship (i.e. via Google API). Otherwise you will haven't access to those kind of relations

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is create a tree/menu structure, and then be able to rapidly retrieve the "breadcrumb" for any given key in the tree.

Here's what I would think:

1. Create the tree with all the branches.  It's okay if you want branches to share keys - as long as you can give the user a "choice" of "Multiple found, please choose which one... ?"
2. For every key in the tree, generate the breadcrumb.  This is time-consuming, and if the tree is very large and updating regularly then it may be something better done offline, in the cloud, or via hadoop, etc.
3. Store the key and the breadcrumb in a key/value store such as redis, or in memory/cached as desired.  You'll want every value to have an array if you want to share keys across categories/branches.
4. When the user selects a key - the key is looked up in the store, and if the resulting value contains only one match, then you simply construct the breadcrumb to take the user where you want them to go.  If it has multiple, you give them a choice.

I would even say, if you need something more organic, say a user can create "new topic" dynamically from anywhere else, then you might want to not use a tree at all after the initial import - instead just update your key/value store in real-time.